# C++ template overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am learning overloading. What is the problem of my codes? Here is the error information `In instantiation of ‘const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _Tp = double; _Compare = double]’:`
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:263:26: error: ‘__comp’ cannot be used as a function
           if (__comp(__a, __b))

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> T1 max(T1,T2,T3);
template <typename T1, typename T2> T1 max(T1,T2);

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 max(T1 x, T2 y){
 return x+y;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
T1 max(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z){
 return x+y+z;
}

int main()
{
        cout << max(1.2,2.3,3.4) << endl;
        cout << max(1,2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: That's not the full error message and `using namespace std;` definitely isn't helping you here (notice how the error says `std::max`).

Comment: BTW, according to implementation, it should be named `sum`, not `max`.

Answer (score 3):

The error message from the compiler clearly indicates that the compiler is using `std::max` instead of the functions defined in the file. That is one more reason why you should avoid

```
using namespace std;
```

To fix your problem:

1. Remove that line.
2. Use `std::cout` and `std::endl` instead of just `cout` and `endl`. If you want to continue to use `cout` and `endl`, add

   ```
   using std::cout;
   using std::endl;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to completely specify which `max` should be called (i.e. the one in std or the one in this file?):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> T1 max(T1,T2,T3);
template <typename T1, typename T2> T1 max(T1,T2);

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 max(T1 x, T2 y){
 return x+y;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
T1 max(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z){
 return x+y+z;
}

int main()
{
        cout << ::max(1.2,2.3,3.4) << endl;
        cout << ::max(1,2) << endl;
}
```

Here using `::max` indicates to the compiler you want max from the root namespace.

Usually, I do not recommend this solution if it can be avoided but this may come in handy.

See https://ideone.com/PWxDT7